# Are there any good examples of Exception Handling Block of Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, exception, mvvm-light, enterprise-library-5

I'm using Enterprise Libray 5.0 version. I'm working on its Exception Handling Block. For this to understand Exception Handling Block I downloaded StockTraderRI Application - (Example Application of Exception Handling). But it uses PRISM Framework.

Is there any example which shows simple silverlight Application using MVVM-Light.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx)? There should be plenty of information there to get you started. In particular look at the Hands-On Labs and the Developer's Guide.

Comment: I already go through it But I am not satisfied with it. B'cos problem came when going to implement it. They already gave a example of stockTraderRI but as I said it uses prism Framework and more complex as I am new'b so I want some simple example that I understand properly.

Comment: Enterprise Library is complex and you will have to read and understand the documentation to implement it correctly. I suggest looking at using a simpler logging library (maybe log4net).
---
Here is a [demo](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/63549) application that I think does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pluralsight has a good video on how to use it.  You may be able to watch it with a trial of the site:  [Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application Block](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=exception-handling)